# java create library for distribution

Tags: java, jar

Excuse me in advance I'm writing with a translator

I have read many posts on the subject but I could not understand the operation.

Use Eclipse on Windows to write in Java 1.8

I created a project (used as a library) with a storied classes that are then used by other projects. I exported the project "library" as JAR and included in other projects, run in Eclipse works.

Now I would like to move the JAR that I exported from the projects and the JAR that use as a library in a Centos but for how many tests did always comes out this error that could not find the classes (that are in the library that I wrote)

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: zjlib/exceptions/CLIOptionArgumentValueRequiredException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:   zjlib.exceptions.CLIOptionArgumentValueRequiredException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 7 more
```

Centos in the library file (called zjlib.jar) is in the directory / home / gexy / lib and I set the valiabile CLASSPATH environment. Using the command

```
java -XshowSettings: properties
```

I see that the CLASSPATH is set correctly in the output in fact I have this

```
[...]
java.class.path = /home/gexy/lib/jzlib.jar
[...]
```

I also tried using the command

```
java -cp ...
```

Hand does not change anything, I still have the error described above when I try to run the jar file that uses my library.

My question is: how can I install my library in the system so that it can start my program with the command

```
java -jar test.jar
```

many thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier to embed your library JAR in the target JAR, as then you will not need to play around with classloaders before your app starts.

I would suggest using Maven for this, as it's a better overall solution, but you can do this is Eclipse too.

Right-click on your project, select Export->Java->Runnable Jar file, select Extract Required libraries into JAR, then fill in the rest of the fields normally.

This method requires that dependencies are known to Eclipse, which will be if your code compiles cleanly and the other library is also an Eclipse project.